# Need to change plain chromadb to langchain chromadb

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, chromadb

```py
import chromadb

client = chromadb.Client()

from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions

# Using OpenAI Embeddings. This assumes you have the openai package installed
openai_ef = embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(
    api_key="sk-key", 
    model_name="text-embedding-ada-002"
)

# Create a new chroma collection
openai_collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name="openai_embeddings", embedding_function=openai_ef)


openai_collection.add(
documents=[
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
      ],    
      ids= ["1", "2", "3"],
)

results = openai_collection.query(
    query_texts=["one"],
    n_results=1
)

print(results)
```

The results will be combination of document and id of the document, i like to do it in langchain for some special search functionality.

But the langchain documentations are only to load the pdf or other files, so i don't need to do with file, i just want to store the text with id in chromadb with langchain.